# Потоки и ui в xcode

Tags: многопоточность, xcode, ui

Доброго времени суток! =)

Суть - нужно при нажатии на кнопку обновить view (добавить индикатор загрузки `progressHUD`), после чего запустить скачивание данных :

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Проблема - никак не получается добавить индикатор ДО загрузки (получается только после нее). Пробовал менять параметр `waitUntilDone:NO` - индикатор добавляется корректно, но, видимо, сбиваются потоки и приложение вылетает.

Пробовал добавлять `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` - безрезультатно =\

Comment: Я думаю, ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь провести ресурсоёмкую операцию (`downloadData`) именно в главном потоке, который используется для действий с UI. Именно поэтому вы не можете обновить интерфейс *до* того, как `downloadData` завершит свою работу.

Comment: @VioLet прошу прощения, забыл добавить что в таблице в cellForRowAtIndexPath грузятся картинки в массив  через
 NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
и, при клике (обновлении) происходит затирание таблицы картинок и запуск downloadData , откуда ссылки на эти картинки будут получены

неужели нет никакого способа вклинить индикатор загрузки?

Answer (score 1):

Cкорее всего, **вы скачиваете данные на главном потоке**, тем самым **блокируя его**, соотвественное все на экране "замирает" на время выполнения этого таска, **выход** есть - грузить все **асинхронно**. Для работы с реквестами рекомендую **AFNetworking**, для работы с **асинхронной загрузкой картинок**, в том числе с активити индикатором загрузки - **SDWebImage**

например, с помощью GCD: берете код загрузки данных и оборачиваете в

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.dataLoadingQueue", NULL); 
dispatch_async(queue, ^{ 
    /* тут все, что касается загрузки и парсинга данные, все NSURL, URLRequest и прочее */ 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         /* таким образом можно вызвать код на main-thread чтобы обновить UI, когда закончит выполняться загрузка */ 
    }); 
});
```

получается, что вы показываете прогресс прямо перед всей этой конструкцией, а в main thread блоке скрываете

Comment: @iFreeman спасибо за ответ )
как раз и использовал SDWebImage, но с ним были просто жуткие тормоза на iPad (до 20 сек при загрузке) поэтому пришлось отказаться..
AFNetworking сейчас загуглю.
а просто так вклиниться и засунуть просто индикатор загрузки progressHUD не получится что ли? =\

Comment: скиньте код как вы грузите данные, можно придумать что-то)

Comment: @iFreeman уже пробовал GCD все равно вылетает =\ 
отписался @VioLet :
 в таблице в cellForRowAtIndexPath грузятся картинки в массив через NSURLRequest urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse response, NSData data, NSError error) и, при клике (обновлении) происходит затирание таблицы картинок и запуск downloadData , откуда ссылки на эти картинки будут получены

Comment: @iFreeman
т.е. мне нужно именно дождаться, когда асинхронная загрузка картинки закончится, чтобы я мог очистить массивы данных и заполнить их снова и отобразить